# Android Facebook SDK integration for deleted application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to create an Android application that users can logged in with their faceobook account too and followed that link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/.Everything works perfectly. I create a facebook application and asking permissions for current user.I tried that with my fb account.But when I remove application from apps tab https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, application not ask for permission again. It still return access token that not have deleted from application list.
Current session prints out same as at below:


**{Session state:CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}**


How can I handle that logic ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when I try to delete the app from facebook app page. I realized that sometimes when you hit delete button, app is not removed and when I try to login again on device it was just using cache results.So I had to hit refresh each time I tried to delete the app again till it's surely removed. I don' t know why this happens but maybe you are having the same problem

Comment: I check that friend already. It's removed @application list and now if I request for new data, Its popup dialog.But It display that message at below:

The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.